# Can't get to <style> in xml file using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml-namespaces, xmldocument, xmlnode

trying to get to `<style>` to modify it, but I can't get any further than `<layouts>`, here is my code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fi.FullName);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("rep", "http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/8.0/");

XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("descendant::rep:layouts", nsmgr);

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
    //XmlNode styleNode = node.SelectSingleNode("style");
    //if (styleNode != null)
    //    Console.WriteLine(styleNode.InnerText);

}
```

So, this works `("descendant::rep:layouts")`, I get to see `(Console.WriteLine=) "layouts"`. But if I try to get further, even if one node at a time,  `(descendant::rep:layouts/layout/reportPages/page/pageBody/contents/crosstab/style)`, there is no single node in the list.. please help!!! My ultimate goal is to modify the "CSS style".

XML file is below (pasted from comment):

```
<report xmlns= developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/8.0/">
  <queries> 
<layouts> <layout> <reportPages> 
   <page name="Page1"> <pageBody> <contents>
    <block> <contents> <block> <crosstab name="Crosstab1" refQuery="Query1"> 
    <style> 
      <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Times New Roman';border:0.75pt solid black" /> <defaultStyles> 
    </style>
```

Comment: Looks like sample XML got lost... Try to add it again (don't forget to mark as code).

Comment: Do you have to use XmlDocument? XDocument (Fx 3.5+) is much easier, esp with namespaces.

Comment: here it is; no, I just have to get the job done. I will look into XDocument...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely all other nodes have some non-empty namespaces (note that empty prefix does not mean "no namespace"). One would need to see XML for better answer.

Yes all your nodes are have "[how to ignore namespaces with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440451/how-to-ignore-namespaces-with-xpath)" set as default namespace, so no nodes have it as prefix. If you want to learn more - click on "xml-namespaces" tag for details. Otherwise use following to ignore namespaces [how to ignore namespaces with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440451/how-to-ignore-namespaces-with-xpath) or prefix node names with namespace prefix as you've done for `layouts` one:

```
XmlNode styleNode = node.SelectSingleNode("rep:style", nsmgr);
```

Comment: I tried to post it, and I can't... what does that mean, if there are empty namespaces, how can I get to it?

Comment: <report xmlns= http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/8.0/" +<queries> -<layouts> -<layout> -<reportPages> -<page name="Page1"> -<pageBody> -<contents> -<block> -<contents> +<block> -<crosstab name="Crosstab1" refQuery="Query1"> -<style> <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Times New Roman';border:0.75pt solid black" /> +<defaultStyles> </style>

Comment: I think I get that part, but why is the node.InnerText empty? -<style> <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Times New Roman';border:0.75pt solid black" /> +<defaultStyles> </style> I thought the InnerText woyuld ve the CSS value=".......". Thanks!

Comment: Because attributes are not innertext.