# Select XML node where namespace is changing between requests in WCF

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, namespaces, request

I have to select specific node from the WCF request        `OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()`

The problem is that namespaces are changeing prefixes between requests:

So once it is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Body>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

and other time it is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:mes="MessageContracts" xmlns:req="RequestMessages" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I assure that I always get Body node correctly?

Comment: It is not the namespace (`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`) which is changing, but the namespace prefix (from `s` to `soapenv`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter what the prefixes are as long as the nodes are using the same namespace consistently (which they are in your example).  You just need to make sure that you create a prefix->namespace mapping for the namespace correctly when you do your selection:

The following code should work as-is for both of your example xmls:

```
// assuming XmlDocument doc has already been loaded with the XML response
XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
XmlNode body = doc.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body", nsm);
```

[Working ideone example](http://ideone.com/rTXcO6)

Comment: Hi. Thanks, I thought exactly the same and I did exactly so at the beginning - but it did not work, and that is the purpose of my post. Let me check again if I haven't make some simple mistake

Comment: Hehe. The problem was really in my Xpath statement. I was selecting xmlReq.SelectSingleNode("bd:Body", ns) - which was giving the null result!
But should't this select all Body nodes in the document?

Comment: No, `bd:Body` would only select Body nodes that were immediately below the context node.  `//bd:Body` would select all Body nodes in the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an XPATH to select the node, you can ignore the namespace (and it's abbreviation prefix) when selecting nodes by selecting on the basis of `local-name()`. There is an example of this in the following SO article:-

- [how to ignore namespaces with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440451/how-to-ignore-namespaces-with-xpath)

For your XML documents above, the following Xpath query will return a count of 1 for both documents.

```
count(/*[local-name() = 'Envelope']/*[local-name() = 'Body'])
```

Comment: haven't checked that solution, but interesting. I will take a look.
Thanks for answer

Comment: No prob. If it was useful a +1 would be great :) Am trying to make 2k.