# XPath how to identify an attribute in a predicate in a namespace-unaware way

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML file:

```
<foo:a xmlns:foo=\"http://www.foo.com\">
    <foo:b foo:bar=\"zar\">
    </foo:b>
</foo:a>
```

To get the **b** nodes with an attribute **bar** having the value "zar" (all in the correct namespace), I can use the XPath expression:

```
/foo:a/foo:b[@foo:bar=\"zar\"]
```

(with "foo" properly bound to "http://www.foo.com" - see code at the end)

However, when I want to do the same in a namespace-unaware way, though I can remove the namespace from the elements by relying on the `local-name()` function, I am not able to remove them from the attribute.

This is the best I can come up with:

```
/*[local-name()='a']/*[local-name()='b' and @foo:bar=\"zar\"]
```

(where `foo` is, regrettably, used to qualify the `bar` attribute).

How can I write the above expression with namespaces completely removed?

Below code has been tested both with and without **Saxon-HE-9.4.jar** on the CLASSPATH and produces correct results, but I can't get the 'foo' namespace prefix out of the second XPath expression!

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;

public class FooMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String xmlSample = "<foo:a xmlns:foo=\"http://www.foo.com\"><foo:b foo:bar=\"zar\"></foo:b></foo:a>";
        XPath xpath = namespaceAwareXpath("foo", "http://www.foo.com");
        {
            System.out.printf("[NS-aware           ] Number of 'b' nodes with foo:bar attribute having the value \"zar\" is: %d\n", 
                              ((NodeList) xpath.compile("/foo:a/foo:b[@foo:bar=\"zar\"]").evaluate(stringToXML(xmlSample, true),
                               XPathConstants.NODESET)).getLength());
        }
        {
            System.out.printf("[NS-aware but using local-name() ] Number of 'b' nodes with foo:bar attribute having the value \"zar\" is: %d\n", 
                              ((NodeList) xpath.compile("/*[local-name()='a']/*[local-name()='b' and @foo:bar=\"zar\"]").evaluate(stringToXML(xmlSample, true),
                               XPathConstants.NODESET)).getLength());
        }
    }


    public static XPath namespaceAwareXpath(final String prefix, final String nsURI) {
        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
        NamespaceContext ctx = new NamespaceContext() {
                @Override
                public String getNamespaceURI(String aPrefix) {
                    if (aPrefix.equals(prefix))
                        return nsURI;
                    else
                        return null;
                }
                @Override
                public Iterator getPrefixes(String val) {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
                @Override
                public String getPrefix(String uri) {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            };
        xpath.setNamespaceContext(ctx);
        return xpath;
    }    

    private static Document stringToXML(String s, boolean nsAware) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(nsAware);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        return builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }


}
```

Comment: @JensErat seen that, it's not exactly the same. It only selects based on attribute name, here I am trying to select based on the value of that attribute. Said attribute to be indicated in a namespace-unaware way.

Comment: You're trying to address an attribute an attribute in a namespace-unaware way, the other question does, too. All difference is between the other author is querying for existence, you will want to compare it with another value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
/*[local-name()='a']/*[local-name()='b' and @*[local-name() = 'bar']=\"zar\"]
```