# how to extract a particular node in xml using xpath in python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, amazon-web-services

I am using [python-amazon product module](http://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/operations.html#common-request-parameters) to do item look up in amazon api.

It returns the `xml` object of this kind. I want to know how to use `xpath` to extract the `hyperlink` of `<IFrameURL>`.

```
<ItemLookupResponse>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <ASIN>0316067938</ASIN>
            <CustomerReviews>
                <IFrameURL>
                http://www.amazon.com/reviews/iframe?akid=[AWS Access Key ID]&asin=0316067938&exp=2011-08-01T17%3A54%3A07Z&linkCode=xm2&summary=0&tag=ws&truncate=256&v=2&sig=[Signature]
                </IFrameURL>
            </CustomerReviews>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

I tried this:
but it did not work:

```
result = api.item_lookup('0316067938', ResponseGroup='Reviews',
     TruncateReviewsAt=256, IncludeReviewsSummary=False)
print result.xpath('//IFrameURL')
```

but this gave empty list

EDIT:

I get this when I do `[x.tag for x in result.xpath('//*')]`:

`['{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}ItemLookupResponse', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}OperationRequest', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}HTTPHeaders', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Header', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}RequestId', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Arguments', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Argument', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Argument', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Argument', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Argument', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Argument', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Argument', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Argument', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Argument', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Argument', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Argument', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Argument', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}RequestProcessingTime', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Items', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Request', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}IsValid', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}ItemLookupRequest', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}IdType', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}ItemId', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}ResponseGroup', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}VariationPage', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}IncludeReviewsSummary', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}TruncateReviewsAt', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Item', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}ASIN', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}CustomerReviews', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}IFrameURL', '{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}HasReviews']`

Edit 2:
I get this now as `http://www.amazon.com/reviews/iframe?akid=HIDDEN&alinkCode=xm2&asin=B00062B6QY&atag=HIDDEN&exp=2014-01-28T07%3A55%3A45Z&summary=0&truncate=256&v=2&sig=HIDDEN%3D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query while ignoring the namespace

```
>>> result.xpath('//*[local-name()="IFrameURL"]/text()')[0].strip()
'http://www.amazon.com/reviews/iframe?akid=[AWS Access Key ID]&asin=0316067938&exp=2011-08-01T17%3A54%3A07Z&linkCode=xm2&summary=0&tag=ws&truncate=256&v=2&sig=[Signature]'
```

Comment: I get `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: `result.xpath('//iframeurl/text()')` is returning empty list

Comment: `[x.tag for x in result.xpath('//*')]` to see whats in there

Comment: I have included what I get in the edit above. I do see `iframeurl` there

Comment: Thanks. that helped, but can you explain what you did above? I have pasted the text I get out. now i have to parse this to get the reviews.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46170/discussion-between-guy-and-user1988876)

Comment: this is the syntax to ignore namespace, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440451/how-to-ignore-namespaces-with-xpath