# Is there a better XPATH syntax than */*/*/*/*[12] when *//.../@NODE does not work?

Tags: xml, xpath

While I am successful in getting (US) PMMS 30Y Fixed Mortgage Rates via XPATH, I am not as successful in getting the (US) Federal Curve Yields. What's different about these XML data sets that makes one work and not the other?

I have tried many variations and the only variation that works **with this data set** is using some series of `*/*/*/*` with an array qualifier `[12]`.

The total  `count(*//)` of elements in this data set is **180**.

I am using Google Sheets IMPORTXML(url,xpath) to perform this action.

**THIS WORKS**

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/XmlView.aspx?data=yield","*/*/*/*/*[12]")`

**THIS DOES NOT**

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/XmlView.aspx?data=yield","*//d:BC_10YEAR")`

**NOR ANY OF THESE**

```
*//*@d:BC_10YEAR
*//@d:BC_10YEAR
*//d:BC_10YEAR[1]
*//m:properties[@d:BC_10YEAR]
*//*m:properties[@d:BC_10YEAR]
```

And many other variations -- I think I have tried them all, but OBVIOUSLY something is eluding me.

The ideal result is to specifically get the latest **BC_10YEAR** which is as of this posting and according to the data set (2019-04-09T20:36:32Z) is **2.49**.

`<d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.49</d:BC_10YEAR>`

**DATA SETS ENCODED URLS**

**US TREASURY:** 
`https://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=month(NEW_DATE)%20eq%204%20and%20year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202019`

**FREDDIE MAC**
`http://www.freddiemac.com/pmms/pmmsthin.html`

With XPATH Query of:

```
http://www.freddiemac.com/pmms/pmmsthin.html        IMPORTXML(url,xpath)
==========================================================================  
XPATH   //th[contains(text(),"30YR")]//..//td[1]    4.08    <== 30YR FMR
XPATH   //th[contains(text(),"30YR")]//..//td[2]    0.5     <== 30YR Fees & Points
```

Comment: Maybe a name space problem. XPath does not know name spaces. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4440451/402322

Comment: Thank you -- good info and insight, reaffirmed by Michael's response as well.  I will try both the 1.0 and 2.0 variants to see if either or both work.  This may also tell us if Google Sheets IMPORTXML function is 1.0 or 2.0 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "better", what are your criteria? Are you after performance, readability, or are you looking for an expression that will still work if there are minor changes to the page content?

Probably the main reason your other attempts are failing is because of namespaces. If there are names in the XPath expression then both the local name and namespace URI need to match with what is in the source document. The way prefixes are bound to namespaces for executing XPath depend on the XPath API you are using, and some people find it more convenient to ignore namespaces by using constructs of the form `*[local-name()='xyz']/*[local-name()='abc']`. In XPath 2.0 you can write `/*:xyz/*:abc`, but I guess if you were using XPath 2.0 you would probably have said so.

Comment: Michael -- thank you. 

By BETTER I meant, a more intelligent and dynamic construct. The construct I am using is bound to the underlying framework (style) of the layout of the document. If the provider changes that format , my construct will not return the desired result.

As for XPath 1.0 or 2.0 -- I honestly don't know.  I am using a Google Sheets IMPORTXML function and I am not able to locate any information about whether it uses 1.0 or 2.0 -- and I personally have not developed the knowledge to discern how to tell the difference. 

I will try your suggestion and post the results.

Comment: I don't think "intelligent" here means anything, but I understand what you mean by "dynamic". Of course any XPath expression is liable to become invalid when the page changes; it's just that some paths are more fragile than others. Screen-scraping is the low life of software engineering, I'm afraid.

Comment: The best documentation I could find for IMPORT_XML was at https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342 -- which points to w3schools of all places for more information on XPath! That doesn't inspire confidence. You can certainly assume with this kind of non-specification that if it supported XPath 2.0, they would say so. The IMPORTXML() api appears to provide no way to bind namespace prefixes, which is a pretty devastating limitation.

Comment: While the **local-name()** certainly makes the query better (less dependent on format), the query `//*[local-name()='BC_10YEAR']` does return the list of rates (each matching node) as expected.  Per `count(//*[local-name()='BC_10YEAR'])` there are **8** items, but I am unable to narrow the query down to a specific item.  

For example: `//*[local-name()='NEW_DATE'='2019-04-10T00:00:00'] and //*[local-name()='BC_10YEAR']` returns TRUE, because `NEW_DATE` is true, but does not return the specific item, or even a list. ...

Comment: Both: `//*[local-name()='BC_10YEAR'][8]` or `//*[local-name()='BC_10YEAR'][last()]` returns the list of each of the **BC_10YEAR** values because that answers the query.  I have tried several variants to no avail. I am confident this is resolvable, but at this moment it escapes me.

I will keep at it and will post the answer when I discover it -- unless some one else beats me to it.

Comment: `//*[local-name()='NEW_DATE'][contains(text(),'2019-04-10')]` returns just the specified date for the node as desired, so I am assuming I am only working with this node.  Using this as the first-level filter, I appended `//*[local-name()='BC_10YEAR']` and get **#N/A**. Yet `//*[local-name()='BC_10YEAR']` will return the list.

Comment: **SOLVED**
`//*[local-name()='NEW_DATE'][contains(text(),'2019-04-10')]//..//*[local-name()='BC_10YEAR']`

Thank you @Michael for heading me in SOME direction.

Comment: **GOOGLE FORMULA** To keep the IMPORTXML() formula clean, I place it in its own cell, with references to a cell with just the URL and another with the XPATH query.  The XPATH query formula is:  `="//*[local-name()='NEW_DATE'][contains(text(),'"&text(today()-1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"')]//..//*[local-name()='BC_10YEAR']"`  Since I only need the previous day's update, I get today and subtract 1 (day) from it. Then reformat the date string to match the XML data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to get a full table that uses uses [IMPORTFEED](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093337) and [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136).

The final product is a single `IMPORTFEED` request at the "A2" cell, that returns something like this:

| Date | 1M | 2M | 3M | 6M | 1Y | 2Y | 3Y | 5Y | 7Y | 10Y | 20Y | 30Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-06T00:00:00 | 0.09 | 0.09 | 0.09 | 0.09 | 0.11 | 0.14 | 0.2 | 0.43 | 0.74 | 1.04 | 1.6 | 1.81 |
| 2021-01-11T00:00:00 | 0.09 | 0.08 | 0.08 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.14 | 0.22 | 0.5 | 0.84 | 1.15 | 1.68 | 1.88 |
| 2021-01-14T00:00:00 | 0.09 | 0.09 | 0.09 | 0.09 | 0.1 | 0.16 | 0.23 | 0.49 | 0.82 | 1.15 | 1.69 | 1.88 |
| 2021-01-20T00:00:00 | 0.08 | 0.08 | 0.08 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.13 | 0.19 | 0.45 | 0.78 | 1.1 | 1.65 | 1.84 |
| 2021-01-25T00:00:00 | 0.07 | 0.08 | 0.09 | 0.09 | 0.1 | 0.13 | 0.17 | 0.42 | 0.73 | 1.05 | 1.61 | 1.8 |

#### TL;DR

To get the most recent 10-year Treasury rate (`BC_10YEAR`):

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(IMPORTFEED("https://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$orderby=NEW_DATE desc&$top=1")," ")),"Select Col12")
```

#### Explanation

#### 1. Use XQuery on the URL

Assume I have a Named Range called `UrlFilterCell`, and it has something like this:

```
="NEW_DATE eq datetime'" & TEXT(TODAY()-1,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
```

You can construct this string to be yesterday, or something exotic, like `year(NEW_DATE) gt 2020 and Id mod 3 eq 0` (which returns every 3rd record where the year is after 2020).

Then the `IMPORTFEED` portion would be constructed with the `$filter=` querystring:

```
IMPORTFEED("https://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter="&UrlFilterCell)
```

#### 2. Exploit the space-delimited `content`

The returned XML is formatted as an Atom feed, with the troublesome fields inside the `<content>`:

```
  <entry>
    ...
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7700</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-10-06T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.08</d:BC_1MONTH>
        ...
```

Nastiness.  Except, when using `IMPORTFEED`, everything inside `<content>` is automatically written out as a space-delimited string:

```
" 7784 2021-02-09T00:00:00 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.06 0.07 0.11 0.19 0.48 0.83 1.18 
1.78 1.95 1.95 "
```

Great! Simply use `SPLIT` to convert each delimited-string into separate columns.

Then, use [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) to select only the values we want.  If we were interested in the date (`Col2`) and all 12 durations (`BC_1MONTH`, ..., `BC_30YEAR`), then the formula would be:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(IMPORTFEED(UrlCell)," ")),"Select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14")
```

Modify the columns to your needs, and don't forget to construct `UrlCell` to your needs. For example, `"SELECT Col12"` would return just the `BC_10YEAR` value.