# Selecting value of an element in xml using xpath in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I want to have the value for element RN (so, 20200121) (i found an example here and modified it)

[image: XML image]

file is located at d:\test.xml

I tried:

```bsh
[xml] $xdoc =  get-content “d:\test.xml”  
$xdoc |  Select-Xml “//RN.value” |  % { $_.Node.InnerText } |  select  -Unique
```

Which fails with error

```
Select-Xml : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Xml'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:10
+ $xdoc |  Select-Xml “//RN” |  % { $_.Node.InnerText } |  select   ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-Xml], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlCommand
```

I also tried:

```bsh
[xml] $xdoc =  get-content “d:\test.xml”
$xdoc |  Select-Xml “//RN.value” |  % { $_.Node.InnerText } |  select  -Unique
```

which gives no error nor output

Comment: Do **not** include code as image; always include code as text in a `code` section.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a namespace resolution issue:

```bsh
$values = $xdoc |Select-Xml '//top:RN/top:value' -Namespace @{top='http://www.test.int'}|%{$_.Node.InnerText} |Select -Unique
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to not refer to the namespaces:  [how to ignore namespaces with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440451/how-to-ignore-namespaces-with-xpath)

```
$xdoc.message.bamessage.rn.value

20200121


select-xml '//*[local-name()="value"]' test.xml | % node

#text
-----
20200121
```